# Find Distance to Nearest Zero in NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a NumPy array:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0])
```

At each index, I want to find the distance to nearest zero value. If the position is a zero itself then return zero as a distance. Afterward, we are only interested in distances to the nearest zero that is to the right of the current position. The super naive approach would be something like:

```
out = np.full(x.shape[0], x.shape[0]-1)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    j = 0
    while i + j < x.shape[0]:
        if x[i+j] == 0:
            break
        j += 1
    out[i] = j
```

And the output would be:

```
array([0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

I'm noticing a countdown/decrement pattern in the output in between the zeros. So, I might be able to do use the locations of the zeros (i.e., `zero_indices = np.argwhere(x == 0).flatten()`)

What is the fastest way to get the desired output in linear time?

Comment: What if there's no 0 to the right?

Comment: Great question, then it should default to the final index (i.e., `x.shape[0] - 1`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** [`Searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to the rescue for linear-time in a vectorized manner (before numba guys come in)!

```
mask_z = x==0
idx_z = np.flatnonzero(mask_z)
idx_nz = np.flatnonzero(~mask_z)

# Cover for the case when there's no 0 left to the right
# (for same results as with posted loop-based solution)
if x[-1]!=0:
    idx_z = np.r_[idx_z,len(x)]

out = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=int)
idx = np.searchsorted(idx_z, idx_nz)
out[~mask_z] = idx_z[idx] - idx_nz
```

**Approach #2 :** Another with some `cumsum` -

```
mask_z = x==0
idx_z = np.flatnonzero(mask_z)

# Cover for the case when there's no 0 left to the right
if x[-1]!=0:
    idx_z = np.r_[idx_z,len(x)]

out = idx_z[np.r_[False,mask_z[:-1]].cumsum()] - np.arange(len(x))
```

Alternatively, last step of `cumsum` could be replaced by `repeat` functionality -

```
r = np.r_[idx_z[0]+1,np.diff(idx_z)]
out = np.repeat(idx_z,r)[:len(x)] - np.arange(len(x))
```

**Approach #3 :** Another with mostly just `cumsum` -

```
mask_z = x==0
idx_z = np.flatnonzero(mask_z)

pp = np.full(len(x), -1)
pp[idx_z[:-1]] = np.diff(idx_z) - 1
if idx_z[0]==0:
    pp[0] = idx_z[1]
else:
    pp[0] = idx_z[0]
out = pp.cumsum()

# Handle boundary case and assigns 0s at original 0s places
out[idx_z[-1]:] = np.arange(len(x)-idx_z[-1],0,-1)
out[mask_z] = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You could work from the other side. Keep a counter on how many non zero digits have passed and assign it to the element in the array. If you see 0, reset the counter to 0

Edit: if there is no zero on the right, then you need another check

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0])
out = x 
count = 0 
hasZero = False 
for i in range(x.shape[0]-1,-1,-1):
    if out[i] != 0:
        if not hasZero: 
            out[i] = x.shape[0]-1
        else:
            count += 1
            out[i] = count
    else:
        hasZero = True
        count = 0
print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the difference between the indices of each position and the cumulative max of zero positions to determine the distance to the preceding zero. This can be done forward and backward.  The minimum between forward and backward distance to the preceding (or next) zero will be the nearest:

```
import numpy as np

indices  = np.arange(x.size)
zeroes   = x==0
forward  = indices - np.maximum.accumulate(indices*zeroes)  # forward distance
forward[np.cumsum(zeroes)==0] = x.size-1                    # handle absence of zero from edge
forward  = forward * (x!=0)                                 # set zero positions to zero                

zeroes   = zeroes[::-1]
backward = indices - np.maximum.accumulate(indices*zeroes) # backward distance
backward[np.cumsum(zeroes)==0] = x.size-1                  # handle absence of zero from edge
backward = backward[::-1] * (x!=0)                         # set zero positions to zero

distZero = np.minimum(forward,backward) # closest distance (minimum)
```

results:

```
distZero
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]

forward
# [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]

backward
# [0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Special case where no zeroes are present on outer edges:

```
x = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0,8,8])

forward:  [9 9 9 0 1 2 3 0 1 2]
backward: [3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 9 9]
distZero: [3 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 2]
```

*also works with no zeroes at all*

**[EDIT]** non-numpy solutions ...

if you're looking for an O(N) solution that doesn't require numpy, you can apply this strategy using the accumulate function from itertools:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]

from itertools import accumulate

maxDist  = len(x) - 1
zeroes   = [maxDist*(v!=0) for v in x]
forward  = [*accumulate(zeroes,lambda d,v:min(maxDist,(d+1)*(v!=0)))]
backward = accumulate(zeroes[::-1],lambda d,v:min(maxDist,(d+1)*(v!=0)))
backward = [*backward][::-1]
distZero = [min(f,b) for f,b in zip(forward,backward)]                      

print("x",x)
print("f",forward)
print("b",backward)
print("d",distZero)
```

output:

```
x [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
f [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
b [0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
d [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

If you don't want to use any library, you can accumulate the distances manually in a loop:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
forward,backward = [],[]
fDist = bDist = maxDist = len(x)-1
for f,b in zip(x,reversed(x)):
    fDist = min(maxDist,(fDist+1)*(f!=0))
    forward.append(fDist)
    bDist = min(maxDist,(bDist+1)*(b!=0))
    backward.append(bDist)
backward = backward[::-1]
distZero = [min(f,b) for f,b in zip(forward,backward)]

print("x",x)
print("f",forward)
print("b",backward)
print("d",distZero)
```

output:

```
x [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
f [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
b [0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
d [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

My first intuition would be to use slicing. If x can be a normal list instead of a numpy array, then you could use

```
 out = [x[i:].index(0) for i,_ in enumerate(x)]
```

if numpy is necessary then you can use

```
 out = [np.where(x[i:]==0)[0][0] for i,_ in enumerate(x)]
```

but this is less efficient because you are finding all zero locations to the right of the value and then pulling out just the first. Almost definitely a better way to do this in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I am sorry, I misunderstood. This will give you the distance to the nearest zeros - may it be at left or right. But you can use `d_right` as intermediate result. This does not cover the edge case of not having any zero to the right though.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0])

# Get the distance to the closest zero from the left:
zeros = x == 0
zero_locations = np.argwhere(x == 0).flatten()
zero_distances = np.diff(np.insert(zero_locations, 0, 0))

temp = x.copy()
temp[~zeros] = 1
temp[zeros] = -(zero_distances-1)
d_left = np.cumsum(temp) - 1

# Get the distance to the closest zero from the right:
zeros = x[::-1] == 0
zero_locations = np.argwhere(x[::-1] == 0).flatten()
zero_distances = np.diff(np.insert(zero_locations, 0, 0))

temp = x.copy()
temp[~zeros] = 1
temp[zeros] = -(zero_distances-1)
d_right = np.cumsum(temp) - 1
d_right = d_right[::-1]

# Get the smallest distance from both sides:
smallest_distances = np.min(np.stack([d_left, d_right]), axis=0)
# np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```