# Change values in array based on distance to other elements in the same array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, indexing

I have a one-dimensional Boolean Array. Later this array is used for indexing over coordinates indicating a certain area in a 3-dimensional Point array. I want to make the edges of this area a little bit more rough/noisy. (True= area_of_interest)
Therefore I want to change the False values in the array based on their distance to the next true value i.e. Values next to a True value are likely to be true while far away ones (further than the cutoff) are unlikely to change.

Input:

bool_array = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False]

sample Output:

func(bool_array) = [False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False]

I came up with a solution however this is incredibly slow for huge data (which for me is the case).

```
decay_prob = lambda x: random() < e ** (-x / 10)

boolean_array = np.asarray([False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False])
cutoff = 3
true_indeces = np.asarray(np.where(boolean_array == True))

for i in range(boolean_array.size):
    distances = np.abs(true_indeces - i)
    # only modify the ones in within a certain area
    if np.any(distances < cutoff):
        # calculate the distances from the current index to the closest True value
        # change the value dependent on the distance (smaller values are more likely to change to true)
        boolean_array[i] = decay_prob(np.min(distances))
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but I also couldn't find anything more pythonic or numpy based.

Comment: If `True` is a standout value, have you tried iterating over `true_indeces` setting "nearby" `boolean_array` values to True if they pass your decay test?

Comment: Ohhhh that makes a lot more sense I'll try that and check if that has any significant speedup thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1.

First, compute the distance from each element of `boolean_array` to the nearest `True` value:

```
import numpy as np 

boolean_array = np.asarray([False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False])

nz = np.nonzero(boolean_array)
distances = np.min(np.abs(np.arange(len(boolean_array)).reshape(-1, 1) - nz), axis=1)
print(distances)
```

This gives:

```
[4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Then, create random `True`/`False` values based on the decay function:

```
randoms = np.random.rand(len(boolean_array)) < np.exp(-distances/10)
print(randoms)
```

We obtain:

```
[False  True  True False  True  True  True  True  True False False False]
```

Finally, modify values based on the `cutoff`:

```
cutoff = 3
out = np.where(distances < cutoff, randoms, False)
print(out)
```

It gives:

```
[False False  True False  True  True  True  True False False False False]
```

**Note.** In the process of computing the array `distances` this method creates a 2-dimensional array that can have as many as `len(boolean_array)` rows and columns. For large arrays this will lead to memory issues.

### Solution 2.

This aims to avoid the memory issues of the above solution. It incorporates an idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60554558/15187728).

```
import numpy as np

#sample data
np.random.seed(123)
boolean_array = np.random.rand(20) < 0.3
cutoff = 3


def right_distance(arr, cutoff):
    """
    Computes the distance to the nearest True value on the right. 
    Values past the last True value will be filled by the cutoff
    value. 
    """
    idx_nz = np.flatnonzero(arr)
    if len(idx_nz):
        last_nz = idx_nz[-1]
    else:
        return np.full(len(arr), cutoff)
    out = np.empty(len(arr), dtype=int)
    out[0] = idx_nz[0]
    out[1:last_nz + 1] = idx_nz[np.cumsum(arr[:last_nz])] - np.arange(1, last_nz + 1)
    out[last_nz + 1:] = cutoff
    return out


def distances(arr, cutoff=None):
    """
    Computes the distance to the closest True value.
    Distances truncated to the cutoff value before the first 
    True value and past the last True value.
    """
    if cutoff is None:
        cutoff = len(arr)
    return np.minimum(right_distance(arr, cutoff),
                      right_distance(arr[::-1], cutoff)[::-1])


d = distances(boolean_array, cutoff)
randoms = np.random.rand(len(d)) < np.exp(-d / 10)
out = np.where(d < cutoff, randoms, False)
```

Comment: Although this is an approved (purely NumPy based ) implementation from mine I encounter some memory problems (namely numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError). I figure is because of the internal storage difference between lists in an array? Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @MichaelHüppe Yes, the calculation of distances to `True` values involves creating an array that may be as large as the square of the size of `boolean_array`. I added another solution that should avoid this issue.